# python requests module: what's the difference between head and get request method

Tags: python, get, python-requests, http-status-codes, head

when I use requests module to check whether a page is available.
for example:

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = "http://www.motie.com/book/29675"
>>> res = requests.head(url)
>>> print res.status_code
404
>>> res = requests.get(url)
>>> print res.status_code
200
```

I got status_code 404 and 200 for HEAD and GET respectively. I don't known why. 
besides, how can I strace the reason. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can see what is happen by placing a snoop. In a linux box, `tcpdump -i any -s 2000 -A host www.motie.com` will show you what are you sending to and receiving from the server.

Answer (score 5):

The web server you contact is free to behave as it feels it should.  In this case it reports that it cannot find an answer for the `head` request even if it can find an answer for the `get` request.  This is not what it should do, but you would need to fix the server to solve this issue.

See some more about the `head` request [here](https://ochronus.com/http-head-request-good-uses/) and of course in the WP [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HEAD_%28HTTP%29#Request_methods).

Actually, I think it is a bug in the server.

Comment: Maybe you're right, HEAD is not suported by server. But I am just a visitor to the server, how can I prove that(the web server doesn't support HEAD method) ?

Comment: Well, it _supports_ it (stating 404 means "not found" not "bad command" or "server error" or similar).  It just doesn't answer it correctly.  According to the HTTP standard upon a HEAD request it should deliver the same thing as upon a GET request minus the contents.  This it clearly does not.